# Calculate the Cartesian product (xprod method) of two Observables

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs, bacon.js

I have one interesting question. Maybe anybody know how could I implement a method like a http://ramdajs.com/docs/#xprod. I have one solution which I found:

```
let as = [1, 2, 3];
let bs = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

Rx.Observable.for(bs, b => {  
  return Rx.Observable.for(as, a => Rx.Observable.just([a, b]));  
}).toArray().subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]));
});
```

Comment: So, does your solution work? If yes, what is your question?

Comment: I need a more better solution. Now I should accumulate all data to a sequence and to sort in a subscribe. But I think that exists another approach.

Comment: Wait, if you want the transposed order, just swap `as` and `bs` in those `.for` loops?

Comment: Oh! Maybe I tired today. Don't see a trivial thing. Yes, probably you are right =)
`let as = [1, 2, 3];
let bs = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

Rx.Observable.for(as, b => {  
  return Rx.Observable.for(bs, a => Rx.Observable.just([b, a]));
  
})./*toArray().*/subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x/*.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])*/);
});`

Comment: FWIW: while you know I'm a *huge* proponent of Rx, if you already have these as Arrays (which you'd have to for this sort of action), it's probably much more efficient/performant to do this with the arrays directly, then convert the result to an Observable.

Comment: Yes you are right. But Matthew Podwysocki shown me how can I create it. This is just the Cartesian product of sets https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/807

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ben Lesh's comment above that, unless there's something async going on, you probably don't need to use an `Observable`.

A plain ES5, array-based solution (which is equivalent to Matt Podwysocki's inner map [solution](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/807#issuecomment-120128422)) could look like:

```
var as     = [1, 2, 3],
    bs     = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
as.flatMap = flatMap;

var product = as.flatMap(pairWithAllBs);

// pairWithAllBs :: Number -> [[Number, String]]
function pairWithAllBs(a) {
    return bs.map(function (b) {
        return [a, b];
    });
}

// flatMap :: @[a], (a -> [b]) -> [b]
// JS does not have a built-in flatMap function.
function flatMap(fn) {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this.map(fn));
}
```

In ES7, using [array comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions), we should be able to just do:

```
[for (a of as) for (b of bs) [a, b]];
```

Comment: I know how it could be implemented in vanilla js =)